# How to set coveragerc and/or setup.cfg to test a package with specific tests location

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage, python-unittest

I am implementing tests on a python package and I try to make them with **pytest**.

The project has the following architecture:

- **package_name/**

  - *__init__.py*
  - *file1.py*
  - *file2.py*
  - *...*
- **tests/**

  - *test_file1.py*
  - *test_file2.py*
  - *...*
- *setup.py*
- *setup.cfg*
- *.coveragerc*

How can I setup pytest to launch all the tests with a single command such as:

```
coverage run setup.py test
```

I tried a few settings, however it seems like pytest do not find the test files in the **tests/** directory.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run the command `pytest tests/`?

You can also try using marker test invocation:

```
@pytest.mark.my_tests
class TestsFilaA:
    def test_something():
        pass

    def test_something_else():
        pass

@pytest.mark.my_tests
class TestsFilaB:
    def test_something_b():
        pass

    def test_something_else_b():
        pass
```

and run the command `pytest -v -m my_tests`

Comment: Your answer is actually more of a comment rather a solution. Try placing it in comments of OPs question.

Comment: i've updated the comment to be more of a solution :)